# How to import cv2 in slurm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-computing, slurm

I have a python program that I am running on slurm. 
My python program is importing different packages. When I am trying to `import cv2`, I am facing the following error:

```
import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

My job script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=myjob
#SBATCH --account=default
#SBATCH --time=2-00:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --partition=m3c
#SBATCH --mem=4000
module load python/3.5.2-gcc4
module load cuda/8.0
module load cudnn/5.1
module load hdf5/1.10.0-patch1
module list
python3 /path/to/pythonscript/mycode.py
```

How can I tackle this issue on `slurm`?

Comment: is there a module named OpenCV in your cluster?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes there is but after loading it again I have the same issue,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that this is a slurm issue by checking to see if the cv2 can be imported outside of a job submission.

```
module load python/3.5.2-gcc4
module load cuda/8.0
module load cudnn/5.1
module load hdf5/1.10.0-patch1
python3 -c 'import cv2'
```

And see if you get an error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: Yes, still the same error. I think cv2 is not installed on cluster. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, if you need help getting cv2 on your cluster you can ask that as a separate question, but I think the `conda` package manger will help

Comment: Thank you very much once again\

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:
`module load OpenCV`

If it still fails then check if OpenCV is installed in the cluster by running `module spider` in the terminal. This command will list all the available modules in the cluster.